# How to announce (beep) the spied asterisk channel that they are being intercepted? (ChanSpy)

Tags: asterisk

When using ChanSpy() to barge-in or listen is it possible to announce the spied channels that they are being intercepted?

The law says you can intercept if you announce the spied channel.

Currently if I do not use the 'q' option Asterisk beeps and says the channel number only to the interceptor. This is silly because the interceptor already knows this. Nothing is played on the intercepted channels!

```
[barge-in]
exten => _*224x.#,1,Macro(user-callerid,)
exten => _*224x.#,n,Answer
exten => _*224x.#,n,NoCDR
exten => _*224x.#,n,Wait(1)
exten => _*224x.#,n,ChanSpy(SIP/1,B)
exten => _*224x.#,n,Hangup
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no way do it like you want with small effort.

Possible solutions on your choice

1) Hire someone who will extend app_spy.c code to play file to other party

2) Use instead transfer to conference, play in conference file you want

3) Create dialplan (above average complexity/expert level required) which will do spychan session,playback first file, after that do other session and connect human.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I was thinking also at option 3. Is this doable with Originate() command or with something else?

Comment: via originate or call files. doesn't metter. but will be second(other) call